# Is there any method by which we can limit the rows in repartition function?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In spark I am trying to limit the numbers of rows to 100 in each partition. But i don't want to write it in the file.. i need to perform more operations on the file before overwriting the records

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using repartition.

to keep n record in each partition you need to repartition your data as total_data_count/repartition=100

For example : i have 100 record now if i want to have each partition 10 records then i have to repartition my data in 10 parts df.repartition(10)

```
>>> df=spark.read.csv("/path to csv/sample2.csv",header=True) 
>>> df.count()
100
>>> df1=df.repartition(10)
>>> df1\
...     .withColumn("partitionId", spark_partition_id())\
...     .groupBy("partitionId")\
...     .count()\
...     .orderBy(asc("count"))\
...     .show()
+-----------+-----+
|partitionId|count|
+-----------+-----+
|          6|   10|
|          3|   10|
|          5|   10|
|          9|   10|
|          8|   10|
|          4|   10|
|          7|   10|
|          1|   10|
|          0|   10|
|          2|   10|
+-----------+-----+
```

here you can see each partition have 10 records